# BigQuery Standard SQL automatically replace null with zero on left join

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working with two tables in BigQuery that roughly follow the following format:

`t1`

```
p1   num1
joe  25
tom  35
tim  20
```

`t2`

```
p1   num2
joe  15
tom  13
```

... and I need to perform a left join. Note that the names in t2 are not the same as the names in t1, and when I perform this left join of t2 onto t1, I'd like for num2 to be zero, not null.

```
SELECT 
  t1.p1, t1.num, t2.num
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.p1 = t2.pi
```

I am aware of the `IFNULL` function, however I **would prefer to avoid** the following solution:

```
SELECT 
  t1.p1, t1.num, IFNULL(t2.num, 0)
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.p1 = t2.p1
```

The reason for this is because I have a very large query with ~5 left joins and ~50 columns, and for all 50 of these columns the nulls should **all be replaced with zeros**. I have noticed that BigQuery lags significantly when I replace all of the `t2.num` lines in the select with `IFNULL(t2.num, 0)`.

I would like to avoid a solution that addresses the problem at the column level (e.g. 50 columns needing IFNULLs), and would much prefer a solution that addresses the null values at the left join level (for the 5 tables).

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** Any thoughts on why the 50 IFNULLs are lagging BigQuery editor would be greatly appreciated. By lag the editor, I literally mean that when I try to type into the Query editor, what I type is taking several seconds to appear. The IFNULLs do not change the amount of data the query processes (~1GB), so I was surprised that they caused so much lag. Understanding this issue could help me write better queries in the future.

**EDIT2**: I realize now that my code example shared is not helpful. Please let me know if a longer code example would help with the problem.

Comment: do you have same "issue" with `COALESCE(t2.num, 0)`? just checking :o)

Comment: will give it a try

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant it appears to lag equally using `COALESCE` and `IFNULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to explore below option / direction (this eliminates use of IFNULL but will require some extra efforts in constructing those extra UNION ALLs for more left JOINs than it is in simple example):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t1.p1, t1.num num1, t2.num num2
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.p1 = t2.p1 
UNION ALL
SELECT p1, num, 0 FROM t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE p1 = t1.p1
)
```

when applied to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row p1  num1    num2     
1   tim 20      0    
2   joe 25      15   
3   tom 35      13
```